# ODAC/Entity Framework Model Update Issues

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-5, odac, multiple-schema

We are looking to introduce odac into our application but I am running into a number of issues and I can't seem to find any solutions that fix our issues.

We are using an oracle database and trying to use ODAC 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1.0) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio.

In our model we would like to have multiple schemas so we can perform cross schema queries. The schemas which we select in the filter for the database connection appear when we are creating the model. However when we try to update our model from the database only the default schema is visible. Sometimes this can be fixed by opening the relevant part of the database in Server Explorer in Visual Studio but this doesn't always work. This fix never works after we add multiple connection strings for the same model (depending on the location of the user will depend on which database the user gets directed to).

The next issue we are having is that we can't the return types of stored procedures to be auto-generate. I have tried to retrieve the column information but it is never able to retrieve the metadata. I have seen a few suggestions of modifying the stored procedures then getting the column information and reverting the stored procedures but this is something we would like to avoid. Also the suggestions don't seem to work on oracle databases (but that could be me, I don't have much experience with databases).

The final issue (this is a minor issue) is that I cannot figure out how to get the generate code to omit underscores from the classes/methods generated. This isn't a huge issue it is purely to make it easier migrating the code we have.